# List directory to json format using jq

Tags: json, list, directory, jq, ls

I've tried to get linux list of my all files and directories in specified path to json format using ls and jq.

Desired output:
[image]

this is all what I have...
ls | jq -R '[.]' | jq -s -c 'add'

Is it possible to build output like above in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

The following only handles vanilla files and is neither portable nor robust but should be sufficient to get you on your way.

The JSON structure that is emitted is very similar to the output of the `tree` program (shown below); in particular, it uses directory components as strings, since that produces an economical
hierarchy allowing queries such as `.a.b` to view details about the directory ‘./a/b’. To provide jq the necessary data, we use `find . -ls`.

#### jqtree

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -ls | jq -nR '
  # Return an object with useful information
  def gather:
    [splits(" +")] as $in
    | { pathname: $in[-1], entrytype: $in[2][0:1], size: ($in[6] | tonumber) };

  reduce (inputs | gather) as $entry ({};
      ($entry.pathname | split("/") ) as $names
      | if ($entry|.entrytype == "-") then
           ($names[0:-1] + ["items"]) as $p
           | setpath($p; getpath($p) + [{name: $names[-1], size: $entry.size}])
        else . end) '
```

#### Demo

```
$ tree
.
|-- a
|   `-- b
|       `-- foo
|-- big
|-- foo
`-- so

$ ~/bin/jqtree
{
  ".": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "big",
        "size": 1025
      },
      {
        "name": "so",
        "size": 667
      },
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "size": 0
      }
    ],
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "foo",
            "size": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: find -ls had an extra column for me. I had to adjust columns numbers 2->3 and 6->7 resulting in this line:
 | { pathname: $in[-1], entrytype: $in[3][0:1], size: ($in[7] | tonumber) };

Answer (score -1):

This Linux works on mips. Not have `find . -ls` (PARAM not available), tree not have.

Maybe someone can compile `tree` package.

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2017-06-29 11:15:20 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: find [-HL] [PATH]... [OPTIONS] [ACTIONS]

Search for files and perform actions on them.
First failed action stops processing of current file.
Defaults: PATH is current directory, action is '-print'

    -L,-follow  Follow symlinks
    -H      ...on command line only

Actions:
    ACT1 [-a] ACT2  If ACT1 fails, stop, else do ACT2
    ACT1 -o ACT2    If ACT1 succeeds, stop, else do ACT2
            Note: -a has higher priority than -o
    -name PATTERN   Match file name (w/o directory name) to PATTERN
    -iname PATTERN  Case insensitive -name
If none of the following actions is specified, -print is assumed
    -print      Print file name
```